# Error 500 plugin restapi openfire

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, openfire

when compile openfire in eclipse and installed plugin restapi
restapi error 500 when  I want access url

- **`enter code here`**Error 500 Server Error

  ### HTTP ERROR 500

  Problem accessing /plugins/restapi/v1/users/admin. Reason:

  ```
      Server Error
  ```

  #### Caused by:

  ```
  java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

  javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
          at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
          at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:651)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
          at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginServlet.handleServlet(PluginServlet.java:410)
          at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginServlet.service(PluginServlet.java:107)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
          at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:226)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
          at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:165)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
          at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
          at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
          at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  ```

  ---

  *Powered by Jetty://*

  ---

  ****

Comment: Which version of Openfire are you using? Have you made any specific changes in Restapi plugin?

Comment: i used version 4.1.3 .i dont made any specific changes in Restapi plugin

Comment: What do you expect to see? You can not use it within a browser. (because you need provide authentication etc. in the headers)